# dnu wrapped assemblies dont really work when published and deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, dnu

I've wrapped some assemblies with dnu wrap to be able to consume from my net451 based project.

I've executed this:

```
dnu wrap --framework net451 c:\whatever\whatever.dll
```

from my solution root folder and it creates the wrap/package/...

For the purposes of development, this stuff works flawless, but the project.json etc contains a crazy absolute or relative path to the wrapped assembly.

Additionally calling dnu publish doesnt re-write the package paths in the nuget packages, and likewise publishing these folders to another machine in which those windows paths dont exist, naturally those packages fail to install.

**My question**, how in the world is this supposed to work. is there some step I am missing here where the paths in the project.json for the projects get updated? Is there a way I should be copying a dll to some place in the solution heirarchy and then wrapping it such that the dnu publish and tryign to restore elsewhere actually works?

super frustrating as I've ported this stuff all over, and cant successfully deploy to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after lots of back and forth w/ many in the community and David Fowler, I finally realized what the problem was here...

My workflow should have been

- dnu build dnu publish --out somefolder
- copy approot, logs, and wwwroot folders to server
- execute approot/web
  (after chmod +x on the web script)

To Re-iterate, or call out explicitly what my problem was, I was assuming I needed to call restore on the server when in-fact I did not.

There are apparently bugs dealing with wrapped assemblies, specifically with dnu wrap, but that wasnt the problem here. David also noted that thats getting some heavy re-working at the moment.